# Taking a 'snapshot' of centos 7

Tags: centos

So I am trying to basically move all my settings/files on my Centos 7 server elsewhere. But I am unsure as to how should go about this.

I researched on what I should do, and I came across a digital ocean topic discussing bacula. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-bacula-server-on-centos-7

Would this be the right thing to use?

Since I am using digital ocean I can just clone the droplet. I guess this can be removed.